# How to get in Xampp - MariaDB?

Tags: logging, xampp, mariadb

I try for hours to create database whit no success using this annoying Xampp/MariaDB. Finally, I think it is because I was not properly logged in. 
It is my localhost so I never knew that it is a problem.
Please, help me to establish **Global Privileges** and start using this tool.

The default Command Prompt shows this:

```
Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.  
44@44-PC c:\xampp
# _
```

When I type : **mysql** in above line, it goes here:

```
Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
44@44-PC c:\xampp
# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

When i try to create a database, it shows this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS phila_rooms;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'phila_roo
ms'
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?  MysqlWorkbench?  Command line tool "mysql"?  Any of those can login as user "root" right after installing, and have `SUPER` privileges.

Comment: how to log as a user "root" using command line tool "MariaDB"?

Comment: If no password:  `mysql -u root`; if root has a password:  `mysql -u root -p` and it will prompt you for the pwd.  Your sample code logged in as `''` instead of `root`.  `''` has no privileges.  `quit` and go back in as root.

Comment: **44@44-PC c:\xampp
# mysql -u root**   Is this the correct enter? How you format the comments? I spend more then 10 trys and nothing happens?

Comment: Backtics around the text.  It works in Questions, Answers, and Comments.  Yes, try that.  It will say "password:no" and either let you in or not.

Comment: Great, I get in and was able to create a database, thanks. Must I do it every time when I start the program? How can I establish a password for admin?

Comment: There are multiple ways to store the pwd; some are quite insecure.  Dig around a see what suits you.